# Debugging a version of Qt Creator and plugins all built from source

Tags: qt, qt-creator

My goal is to be working on / debugging qt creator plugins and, maybe, editing / debugging qt creator source code. Towards this end I've tried a couple of things:

1. Downloading source for the qt sdk and qt creator, compiling each, and then making a qt creator plugin project and hooking everything together by hand. This got complicated pretty quickly (I tried to keep my plugin project outside the qt-creator/src/plugin/ folder) and doesn't really get me to a nice spot in terms of debugging.
2. Using an installed version of the qt creator to open the qtcreator.pro that came along with the source, adding a qt creator plugin as a sub project, and building everything from the already installed version of qt creator.

I like the second approach a lot because I have control over everything but I can rely on qt creators tools that make projects, enhance debugging, etc. There's just one small problem...

When I run my shiny new build of qt creator (with my plugin project) from inside the installed version all I get is a popup called "qtcreator_process_stub" that says "This is an internal helper of Qt Creator. Do not run it manually. Press  to close this window..."

So I'm not really sure how to debug my build of qt creator from my instance of qt creator. Any ideas? Note: if I run the generated Qt Creator.app I get a functioning instance of qt creator with my plugin loaded properly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this was a versioning problem. I had an older version of the ide installed and was using it to build and debug a newer version of the ide.

I was able, in the older ide, to launch and debug the new ide as an external process through the debug menu... but that was mildly annoying.

Once I installed a new version of the ide I was able to debug like normal.